# How can I get key values and correspond it to each other in js?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an array of objects as follow:

```js
[
    {
        "card_key": "Edition",
        "card_value": "Elite Fight Night"
    },
    {
        "card_key": "Card ID",
        "card_value": "15824885587"
    }
]
```

and I want the output as follow:

```js
{
  "Edition":"Elite Fight Night",
  "Card ID":"15824885587"
}
```

How can I do this in javaScript? I m beginner of js. Not know how can I do this

Comment: No.  object has always 2 keys in my scenario

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just iterate through the array and save the value of `card_key` as key and `card_value` as the value for your new object.

Something as shown below

```js
    
obj_array = [
    
    {
        "card_key": "Edition",
        "card_value": "Elite Fight Night"
    },
    {
        "card_key": "Card ID",
        "card_value": "15824885587"
    }
    ]

objs1 = {}

for (const x of obj_array)

    objs1[x["card_key"]] = x["card_value"]

console.log(objs1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `map` and `Object.fromEntries`

```js
const data = [
    {
        "card_key": "Edition",
        "card_value": "Elite Fight Night"
    },
    {
        "card_key": "Card ID",
        "card_value": "15824885587"
    }
]

const result = Object.fromEntries(data.map(d => [d.card_key, d.card_value]))

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let arr = [
{
    "card_key": "Edition",
    "card_value": "Elite Fight Night"
},
{
    "card_key": "Card ID",
    "card_value": "15824885587"
}
];
let finalObj = {};
for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    let obj = arr[i];
    finalObj[obj['card_key']] = obj['card_value'];
}
console.log(finalObj);
```

Comment: Thanks man! your code and @Art code works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

If data has structure that you provided, you can use this code:

```js
const input = [
    {
        "card_key": "Edition",
        "card_value": "Elite Fight Night"
    },
    {
        "card_key": "Card ID",
        "card_value": "15824885587"
    }
];
const expectedData = input.reduce((acc, item) => ({...acc, [item.card_key]: item.card_value}), {});
console.log(expectedData);
```

This is a bracket notation that allowing to use dynamic object keys.

Links:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors

https://javascript.info/object

Reduce it is a function, that allows to calculate value based on input array. You can read about reduce here:

https://javascript.info/array-methods#reduce-reduceright

And also about spread operator (...):

https://javascript.info/rest-parameters-spread#spread-syntax

Answer (score 0):

```js
const data = [{
    "card_key": "Edition",
    "card_value": "Elite Fight Night"
  },
  {
    "card_key": "Card ID",
    "card_value": "15824885587"
  }
]

console.log(data.reduce((a, c) => {
  a[c.card_key] = c.card_value;
  return a
}, {}))
```